# how to add JSON framework

Tags: iphone, ios, json

Goal : Add the latest JSON into my project.

I download JSON from this link https://github.com/stig/json-framework/downloads and drag the folder name **stig-json-framework-a23638b** in my project. and Check “Copy items into destination group’s folder (if needed)”.

**stig-json-framework-a23638b** folder shows many sub folder inside like **Classes, Examples, SBJSON, sbjson-ios, sbjson-iosTests.**

after that when I #import "JSON.h" it gives error JSON.h file not found.

I know I am doing wrong please direct me in right direction. and provide me link from where I download JSON Framework. and any good tutorial links.

many thanks.

Comment: Do you need to support pre-ios5?  If not,see NSJSONSerialization class built in to ios5

Comment: @bryanmac yes i need to support pre-ios5.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You dont need to import the whole project with examples and target of it.Just import whatever in the "`classes`" folder in that framework..

https://github.com/stig/json-framework/tree/master/src/main/objc

Files listed in above link is enough to import framework.

As @sanchitsingh said, you need to import only "`SBJSON.h`".

Answer (score 1):

There is no file JSON.h.

Try this

```
#import "SBJson.h"
```

Comment: thanks. when i import "SBJson.h" in not gives error. what is difference between JSON.h and SBJSON.h?

Comment: The file name is SBJSON.h not JSON.h. Accept my answer if it helped you also +1 it.